# Split command output in multiline blocks to be further processed

Tags: linux, openssl

I am trying to split the output of an openssl command which returns multiple certificates in base64 with some characters in between:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
```

I want each certificate (including the begin and end lines) then passed again to another openssl command for decoding.

command 1: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.com:443`
command 2: something with awk I suppose, but I cannot figure it out.
command 3: `openssl x509 -text -noout`

`command 1 | command 2 | command 3`

in the end I should see multiple decoded certificates in the standard output, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done the way you want it, with a single pipe - you need to create a processing pipe for each individual file.
What you can do is to separate the certificates into multiple files and process those in a loop afterwards, or create a temp file and process that; either way, it is an iterative process, something like:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{i=0;}
  /^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----$/{i=1;}
  {
    if(i){print > "/tmp/delme.crt";}
  }
  /^-----END CERTIFICATE-----$/{
    i=0;
    system("cat /tmp/delme.crt");
    close("/tmp/delme.crt");
  }' <(cat <<eof
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert1>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert2>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert3>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
eof
)
```

where the `cat` command invoked with `system` by awk would be the processing of the certificate in this case and, instead of `cat << eof ...` you could use the openssl command that gives you the output you described.

To dump the certs in separate files you would:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{i=0;j=100;}
  /^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----$/{i=1;}
  {
    if(i){print > "/tmp/certificate"j".crt";}
  }
  /^-----END CERTIFICATE-----$/{
    i=0;
    close("/tmp/certificate"j++".crt");
  }' <(cat <<eof
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert1>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert2>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 cert3>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
<random characters>
eof
)
```

and then you can process them:

```
for i in /tmp/certificate*.crt; do echo "Processing file $i"; done
```

outputs

```
Processing file /tmp/certificate100.crt
Processing file /tmp/certificate101.crt
Processing file /tmp/certificate102.crt
```

Comment: I feared this answer... Thanks a lot anyway!